# How to do typing and stop typing in socket.io and jquery properly?

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I know that [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat) released the source for chat app, but for somehow I couldn't understand all of the components.

I Read one of great SO [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766488/socket-io-how-to-check-if-user-is-typing-and-broadcast-it-to-other-users) as well, but still couldn't figure out how to do it properly.

Here's my attempt

ClientSide

```
function timeoutFunction() {
    typing = false;
    socket.emit("typing", false);
  }


  $('.typing-message').keyup(function() {
    console.log('happening');
    typing = true;
    socket.emit('typing', 'typing...');
    timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 2000);
  });


  socket.on('typing', function(data) {
    if (data) {
      $('.typing').html(data);
    } else {
      $('.typing').html("");
    }
  });
```

ServerSide

```
 socket.on('typing', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
    });
```

It does work, but its not working as I imagine, the problem comes when **Im typing for longer period** the state `$('.typing').html();` is keep changing between typing.. and '' constantly. This only happen if I type for longer period.

How to do this feature properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `keyup` handler, you need to clear the previous timeout before setting a new one:

```
var timeout;

function timeoutFunction() {
    typing = false;
    socket.emit("typing", false);
}

$('.typing-message').keyup(function() {
    console.log('happening');
    typing = true;
    socket.emit('typing', 'typing...');
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 2000);
});

socket.on('typing', function(data) {
    if (data) {
        $('.typing').html(data);
    } else {
        $('.typing').html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: a more better version
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766488/socket-io-how-to-check-if-user-is-typing-and-broadcast-it-to-other-users